# Zend_Mail and Google Apps strange behavior

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, zend-mail

Seems that you can't modify the "From" header...always map to x@gmail.com or x@domain.com. Also, keeps adding a CC header to the sender. Is this normal?

Comment: Please add some more info about what you're doing and what you are running this on.

Comment: What is your code? What are some examples of the Raw Email Messages? How are you sending the email? We can only help you if you give us a better idea of what you are doing, what you are seeing, any why it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal. I was also wondering about this, and after a bit of a googling, I found out that Google just replaces the `from` header. No way to change this behavior. Set the `reply-to` header, that's the best you can do.

Edit, a clarification to others: when using Google's SMTP servers for sending out emails from your web application, no matter what you set for the `from` header, it'll just replace it with your Google account you're using to send the emails.